# Erro ao imprimir valores, os valores que são impressos não têm nada a ver com os que foram guardados

Tags: c++, impressão, visual-studio-2017

Acontece que as funcoes gets não retornam qualquer tipo de valor.
  E a funcao getMedidasPC(); devolve sempre os valores
-858993460-858993460 independentemente do que é escrito

```
Clientes.h

void getMedidasPC();
void setLargPC(int x);
int getLargPC();
void setAltPC(int y);
int getAltPC();

private:
int largPC;
int altPC;
```

clientes.cpp

```
void Cliente::getMedidasPC()
{
cout << largPC << "mm x" << altPC << "mm" << endl;
cout << largPC;
cout << altPC;
}
void Cliente::setLargPC(int x)
{
largPC = x;
}

int Cliente::getLargPC()
{
return largPC;
}

void Cliente::setAltPC(int y)
{
altPC = y;
}

int Cliente::getAltPC()
{
return altPC;
}´
```

Main.cpp

```
int main(){
int xPC;
int yPC;

cout << "\n Largura:" << endl;
cin >> xPC;
clienteObj.setLargPC(xPC);
cout << "\n Altura:" << endl;
cin >> yPC;
clienteObj.setAltPC(yPC);

clienteObj.getLargPC(); //FUNCAO NAO ESTA A FUNCIONAR(não imprime nada)
clienteObj.getAltPC(); // ""     ""   ""  "" ""

cout << xPC << "e" << yPC << endl; //aqui é impresso '400e700'

clienteObj.getMedidasPC();//aqui é impresso -858993460mm x-858993460mm
```

-858993460-858993460

```
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Onde foi declarado o `clienteObj` ? Não aparece em lado nenhum no seu código. De qualquer forma não consegui reproduzir o seu problema. [Veja o seu código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bMLbDF)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você tem que inicializar `int largPC` e `int altPC` antes de atribuir um valor pra elas, você pode fazer isso no construtor da classe, tipo `Cliente::Cliente() : largPC(0), altPC(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

As funcoes `getLargPC` e `getAltPC` retornam um inteiro, mas isso nao quer dizer que esse inteiro sera impresso automaticamente

Voce precisara fazer isso para imprimir o resultador retornado por essas funcoes:

```
cout << "Resultado de getLargPC: " << getLargPC() << endl;

cout << "Resultado de getAltPC: " << getAltPC() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código possui vários erros de sintaxe, e nem ao menos compila.

Sua classe `Clientes` não possui um construtor no qual os atributos de classe `altPC` e `largPC` poderiam ser inicializados adequadamente, o que evitaria esses *estranhos* valores retornados.

Segue seu código reescrito de forma que compile e funcione como o esperado.

**Cliente.h**:

```
#ifndef CLIENTE_H
#define CLIENTE_H

class Cliente
{
    public:

        Cliente();    // Construtor
        ~Cliente();   // Destrutor

        void exibirMedidas();

        void setLargura(int x);
        int getLargura();

        void setAltura(int y);
        int getAltura();

    private:

        int largura;
        int altura;
};

#endif
```

**Cliente.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cliente.h"

Cliente::Cliente()
{
    largura = 0;
    altura = 0;
}

Cliente::~Cliente()
{
}

void Cliente::exibirMedidas()
{
    std::cout << largura << "mm x " << altura << "mm" << std::endl;
}

void Cliente::setLargura(int x)
{
    largura = x;
}

int Cliente::getLargura()
{
    return largura;
}

void Cliente::setAltura(int y)
{
    altura = y;
}

int Cliente::getAltura()
{
    return altura;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cliente.h"

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
    Cliente c;
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Entre com a Largura: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Entre com a Altura: ";
    cin >> y;

    c.setLargura(x);
    c.setAltura(y);

    c.exibirMedidas();

    cout << "Largura: " << c.getLargura() << endl;
    cout << "Altura: " << c.getAltura() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Entre com a Largura: 100
Entre com a Altura: 200
100mm x 200mm
Largura: 100
Altura: 200
```

Comment: só copiei para aqui uma parte do codigo, por isso é normal ter me enganado em alguma coisa, obrigado!